# how to use my database on AWS

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin

I'm using linux, and I've been trying to import my database mysql to my AWS instance, I downloaded all the tools. 
`php, mysql-server,apache2` and the AWS instance is running.

I'm using FileZilla to upload the files, and I'm connected to the server fine, but whenever I try to open `myphpadmin` it won't work, showing me weird things on the screen.

Adding a pic for reference

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about the AWS; you should prepare the LAMP env at first.

To install and start the LAMP web server with the Amazon Linux AMI

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install -y httpd24 php70 mysql56-server php70-mysqlnd
sudo service httpd start
sudo chkconfig httpd on
```

For more info read the following article
[Tutorial: Install a LAMP Web Server with the Amazon Linux AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html)